# $Ra=\langle a\rangle$ for ring $R$ and $a \in R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am reading some proofs of "$R$ is a field iff only ideals of $R$ is $\{0\}$ and $R$" and in the process of reading, I have a question.

In the converse parts, the textbooks say

> Let $a \in R$, then $Ra$ is the ideals of $R$. If $a=0$, then $Ra=\{0\}$. If $a\neq 0$, then $Ra=\langle a\rangle \neq \{0\}$. From the assumption $Ra=\langle a\rangle=R$ and since $1\in R=Ra$, $1=ra$, $r \in R$, so $r=a^{-1}$, .i.e., $a$ have an inverse.

What I can not understand is $Ra=\langle a\rangle$. I understand $\langle a\rangle \subset Ra$ But how one can understand $Ra \subset \langle a\rangle$?

Comment: What is your definition of $\langle a \rangle$?

Comment: And what is $\langle a\rangle$?

Comment: The statement is false if you do not assume $R$ is commutative with a unity. You need to **say so**.  And as others have noted, you need to say what your notation means. Usually, $\langle a\rangle$ means “the smallest ideal of $R$ that contains $a$“. With that definition, it is $Ra\subseteq\langle a\rangle$ which should be obvious.

Comment: I see, Maybe I was confused with other notation $<a>= \{a,a^2,\cdots\}$.

Comment: $\langle a\rangle=\{ar : r\in R\}$ and by assumption it must be the only non-zero ideal $R.$ Perhaps now you can answer to your own question.

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`; cf. $\langle a\rangle$ and $<a>$. No, $\langle a\rangle$ would never mean only the positive powers of $a$. If you don’t know what notation means, then you won’t understand the arguments. And if you don’t state the full context, what you write is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement that $R$ is a field is trivially false if $R$ is not commutative (since it can never be a field); and a counterexample is given by both the quaternions (a division ring), and the ring of $2\times 2$ matrices over a field (which is not a field and not a division ring, but is simple).

The statement is false if we do not assume $R$ to have a $1$: the cyclic group of order $2$ with zero multiplication has no ideals other than the trivial ones, but is not a field.

So you need to **state** that $R$ is commutative with unity, otherwise the whole thing collapses.

By definition, $\langle a\rangle$ is the smallest ideal of $R$ that contains $a$. For an arbitrary ring (not necessarily commutative, not necessarily with $1$), you should prove that
$$\langle a\rangle = \left.\left\{na + ra + as + \sum_{i=1}^kr_ias_i\,\right|\, n\in\mathbb{Z},k\in\mathbb{N},r,s,r_i,s_i\in R\right\}.$$

By definition,
$$\begin{align*}
Ra &= \{ra\mid r\in R\}\\
aR &= \{ar\mid r\in R\}\\
RaR &= \left\{\sum_{i=1}^k r_ias_i\,\Bigm|\, k\in\mathbb{N}, r_i,s_i\in R\right\}.
\end{align*}$$
You should verify that $Ra$ is a left ideal, $aR$ is a right ideal, and $RaR$ is a two-sided ideal.

When $R$ has a unity, you should prove that $RaR=\langle a\rangle$.

When $R$ is commutative, you should prove that $Ra=aR=RaR$.

When $R$ is commutative and has a unity, you should prove that $Ra=aR=RaR=\langle a\rangle$.